# Expectation and variance of X − Y

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let's say I have $X=\min\{X_1,...,X_{10}\}$ with the $X_i\sim Exp(\lambda_i)$ independent.

And let $Y=\min\{X_{11},...,X_{20}\}$

What is the *expectation* and *variance* of $X-Y$?

I really don't know where to start.

So far I have the following:

$X \sim Exp(\sum_{i=1}^{10} \lambda_i)$

$Y \sim Exp(\sum_{i=11}^{20} \lambda_i)$

And I know that $X-Y|X>Y \sim X, \quad \quad X-Y|X<Y \sim -Y$

But how to go from there?

Comment: Are the $X_1,\dots,X_{20}$ independent?

Comment: @drhab: Yes they are

Comment: how did you get that $X~Exp(\sum_{i=1}^{10} \lambda_i)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- $\mathbb E(X-Y)=\mathbb EX-\mathbb EY$
- if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $\operatorname{Var}(X-Y)=\operatorname{Var}X+\operatorname{Var}Y$

Comment: wow I feel dumb now :P. Totally forgot about that. One more question: what is $Var X$ and $Var Y$? (I don't know how to calculate $E[X^2]$ and $E[Y^2]$)

Comment: If I am correct then $\lambda^{-2}$. You can find it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).

Comment: So $Var[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{10} \lambda_i^{-2}$ ?

Comment: No. It equals $(\sum_{i=1}^{10}\lambda_i)^{-2}$

Comment: Well done, good and faithful servant!

Comment: At your service, and glad to help.